# How to edit the color of the sort glyph when using ng-table?

Tags: css, angularjs, ngtable

In a table made using AngularJS ng-table, very similar to: 
http://ng-table.com/#/demo/2-1
i have to change the colour of the sort symbol for default/ascendent/descendent and normal/hover/active state.
I assume it's done by CSS(SASS) but what is the selector and how you can use it in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It is in CSS following are the two classes:

CSS for up arrow and ascending Sorting:

```
.ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:after, {
      border-color: #AB8383 transparent;
    }
```

and CSS for down arrow:

```
.ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:before{
  border-top: 4px solid #4D1F4B;
}
```

Descending Sorting:

```
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-desc .sort-indicator:after{
border-top: 4px solid #420A0A;
}
```

For hover you may use:

```
.ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:hover:after, .ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:hover:before{
//css rule here
}
```

Comment: Great! But what selector to use for default sort-indicator (the one containing both arrows)?

Comment: The one containing both up and down arrow are in answer as up arrow and down arrow. `.ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:after` for up arrow and `.ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:before` for down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite some classes:

```
.ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:before,
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-desc .sort-indicator:after, 
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-desc .sort-indicator:hover:after{
  border-top: 4px solid #4D1F4B;
}

.ng-table th.sortable .sort-indicator:after,
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-asc .sort-indicator:after, 
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-asc .sort-indicator:hover:after{
  border-bottom: 4px solid #4D1F4B;
}
```